# Json.NET fails to serialize https response message

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, windows-store-apps, certificate

The code is simple enough:

```
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, 
    new Uri("https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png", UriKind.Absolute));
HttpResponseMessage response = await new HttpClient().SendRequestAsync(request);
string str = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
```

And it throws a **Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException**

> Error getting value from 'IsStronglyProtected' on 'Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.Certificate'.

If I request the same url, but use plain HTTP instead of HTTPS, it works fine, the serialized string is

> {"Version":2,"StatusCode":200,"Source":2,"RequestMessage":{"RequestUri":"http://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png","Method":{"Method":"HEAD"},"Content":null,"Headers":{"Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate"},"Properties":{},"TransportInformation":{"ServerCertificate":null,"ServerCertificateErrorSeverity":0,"ServerCertificateErrors":{},"ServerIntermediateCertificates":{}}},"ReasonPhrase":"OK","Content":{"Headers":{"Content-Length":"5087","Last-Modified":"Thu, 08 Dec 2016 01:00:57 GMT","Content-Type":"image/png","Expires":"Fri, 21 Apr 2017 12:37:29 GMT"}},"Headers":{"Server":"sffe","Cache-Control":"private, max-age=31536000","Accept-Ranges":"bytes","Date":"Fri, 21 Apr 2017 12:37:29 GMT","X-Content-Type-Options":"nosniff","X-XSS-Protection":"1; mode=block"},"IsSuccessStatusCode":true}

The `Newtonsoft.Json` version is 10.0.1, the code is written in a Windows Store app targeting 8.1.

I tried to create a **Console project** to verify this issue using the `Newtonsoft.Json` library for .NET4.5 (the version is 10.0.2) but there is no such issue. The result for the same HTTPS url is

> {"m_HttpResponseHeaders":["X-Content-Type-Options","X-XSS-Protection","Alt-Svc","Accept-Ranges","Content-Length","Cache-Control","Content-Type","Date","Expires","Last-Modified","Server"],"m_Uri":"https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png","m_Certificate":null,"m_Version":{"Major":1,"Minor":1,"Build":-1,"Revision":-1,"MajorRevision":-1,"MinorRevision":-1},"m_StatusCode":200,"m_ContentLength":5087,"m_Verb":"HEAD","m_StatusDescription":"OK","m_MediaType":null}

Comment: Does it make any difference if you change your code like this: `var response = new HttpClient().SendAsync(request).Result;`?

Comment: no difference. You're just calling the asynchronous API synchronously

Comment: Why are you trying to serialize a `HttpResponseMessage`?  Normally you would just return this object from a Web API method and let the framework handle the serialization of the content.  What are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: That is another story, we want to get the last modified time, which should be OK by just reading one of the headers. During debugging I find this symptom so I wonder what it is since I can't find useful info on the web.

Comment: Have you read this thread? It looks like a similar  problem: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/290df555-15c6-4a91-aefc-4895309c5822/how-to-use-httpclient-or-httpwebrequest-to-consume-https-secure-web-services-in-windows-phone-81?forum=wcf